# Make a copy and launch an executable with Python, giving the process a randomized name

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to launch an executable with Python but give it a different process name.  As an example of why, the page for [Rootkit Revealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx) mentions that it is now called by a service that makes a copy of the executable with a random name and runs it.  This helps it track malware that won't run if it detects presence of Rootkit Revealer.  This is inspired by [this question in security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54910/how-to-identify-and-analyze-malware-that-checks-for-security-tools-before-runnin/55579#55579)

Rootkit Revealer is abandoned now but Malware still wants to avoid software like Wireshark and process monitor.  Following along at home, this is what I came up with:

```
import psutil
import subprocess
import shutil

randomString = "saf9dsfjkoopY.exe"
shutil.copy("C:\\Windows\System32\\notepad.exe",randomString)
p = subprocess.Popen(randomString)

# Look for process by name
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        process_info = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid','name'])
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        pass
    else:
        if process_info['name'] == "TextPad.exe":
            print(process_info)
        if process_info['name'] == "notepad.exe":
            print(process_info)
```

Do you think the first part would work in renaming the process and evading malware?  What would I gain by making the executable run as a service instead of a regular process?  The [malware in question](http://pastebin.com/m46ed5911) uses the following code to avoid certain security tools:

```
std::vector<DWORD> SetOfPID;
        GetProcessID("Wireshark",SetOfPID);
        if (SetOfPID.empty())
        {
                // Nothing found running, Safe to execute bot.
        }
        else
        {
                // One of the process was found running, Exit install.
                // If you want to you could also make it kill connections or cut process. ~ h1t3m
        ExitProcess(0);
```

Comment: What happens if you specify `Popen([randomString], executable='notepad.exe')`?

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: What happens if you provide the full path to `notepad.exe`? Or swap it and `randomString`?

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions.  Using the full path in that statement  opens notepad under process name "notepad.exe".  Reversing the order gives "SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg"

Comment: Do you mean that after `Popen([randomString], executable=r'c:\full\path\notepad.exe')` call `psutil` finds `process_info['name'] == 'notepad.exe'` and not `randomString`? And by swapping I meant: `Popen([r'c:\full\path\notepad.exe'], executable=randomString)` (it should fail)